# Megaraid Firmware fault

Tags: ibm, megaraid

After building a new server (IBM X3550). Getting error

Firmware is in Fault state: MFI register state 0xF0FF2102. -- For this one could not get any help in google.

And on the BIOS system setting getting the message:

Driver Health Protocol: Missing configuration requires changes setting F1. -- now for this error I went to IBM site and it does not say much only says "Set the appropriate settings'.

I know this is most likely an hardware problem, but still I wanted to know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be Hardware problem. The Cache attached to the controller was faulty. After replacing the DIMM it issue got resolved.

Comment: Glad you resolved this. Please be sure to [mark your answer accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) when you are able.

Comment: This turned out to be the correct answer for a similar message with my megaRAID card as well - FW fault 0xFFFFFFFF and boot loop. The battery (or battery board) for the Cache was dud, removing it from the RAID card immediately resolved the boot loop. The above Q and answer helped identify the issue